# How to create an angled corner edge in CSS

Tags: css

My main site container follows a pretty unusual path, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement it, mainly the angled part in the middle.

hopefully I can do this via CSS, though I'm open to other alternatives. I've done a lot of searching, and found things that somewhat apply to this, but nothing specifically.

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @uthark - why? They are after a CSS solution, I see no reference to wordpress at all!

Comment: There was a reference to Wordpress in the original question but I edited it out because the actual question had nothing to do specifically with Wordpress.

Comment: @JonP initially question stated wordpress + it was not clear if the question doesn't involve wordpress specifics css.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/54raksui

```
.edge{position:relative;background-color:#cccccc;border:1px solid #ffffff;display:inline-block;}
.edge img{display:block;}
.edge:before{content:'';position:absolute;left:-1px;top:-1px;border-top:50px solid #ffffff;border-right:50px solid transparent;}
.edge:after{content:'';position:absolute;left:-2px;top:-2px;border-top:50px solid white;border-right:50px solid transparent;}

<div class="edge">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" alt="" />
</div>
```